# How to profile OpenCL application with CUDA 8.0 nvprof

Tags: cuda, profiling, opencl, nvprof

I'm trying to profile OpenCL application, `a.out`, in a system with NVIDIA TITAN X and CUDA 8.0.

If it was CUDA application, `nvprof ./a.out` would be enough. But I found this does not work with OpenCL application, with a message "No kernels were profiled."

Until CUDA 7.5, I successfully used `COMPUTE_PROFILE=1` following [this](http://uob-hpc.github.io/2015/05/27/nvvp-import-opencl.html). Unfortunately, the documentation says "The support for command-line profiler using the environment variable COMPUTE_PROFILE has been dropped in the CUDA 8.0 release."

The question is, is there any way other than downgrading CUDA to profile OpenCL application with nvprof?

Comment: Are you calling `clReleaseContext ` within your application?

Comment: @talonmies Yes, it properly calls release functions for context, queue, program, kernel, and memory object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, `nvprof` has never supported OpenCL profiling.

Running code with `COMPUTE_PROFILE=1` invokes a driver based profiling mechanism which predates the introduction of `nvprof`. That driver based mechanism was deprecated a while ago and has now been removed as of CUDA 8 in favour of using `nvprof`.

As a result, it would appear that there is no way to profile OpenCL code running on NVIDIA hardware using the CUDA toolkit.